# Change quote currency before place order

Tags: magento2, event-observer, sales-order, quote, currency

I want to change my quote currency code to EUR when an order is placed in any other currency.

I tried writing event and observer of event `sales_order_place_before`.
In my observer I have this code

```
    $quoteId = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder()->getQuoteId();
    $quote = $this->cartRepository->get($quoteId);
    $this->storeManager->getStore()->setCurrentCurrencyCode('EUR');
    $quote->setQuoteCurrencyCode("EUR");
    $quote->collectTotals();
    $this->cartRepository->save($quote);
```

But after order is placed currency did not change to Euro.

I tried another event `sales_quote_save_after`, where currency is changed after every save of quote, but in that case, even the customer will see that his cart currency is changed to EUR, which I don't want. I only want to change the currency when order is being placed (the customer should not be shown this anywhere, except on my orders)

Comment: try this $quote->save();

Comment: I tried it, but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of sales_order_place_before && sales_quote_save_after use this event sales_model_service_quote_submit_before and write your logic for this but don't call save function in the observer

Comment: let me know if any issues

Comment: I tried with the sales_model_service_quote_submit_before, it din't work. In my observer if I die and execute again without die, the order is placed in EUR currency. Any suggestions on this?

Comment: what do you mean by " In my observer if I die and execute again without die means" can you please elaborate.

Comment: At the end of my observer I wrote die, the order was not paced but the quote currency was updated to EUR, next I remove the die, and again place the same order the order is placed in EUR.

Comment: is every thing is fine now?

Comment: No order currency is not been changed

Comment: can you share the screen shot?

Comment: this is what i am doing in my observer  
$quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();
$this->storeManager->getStore()->setCurrentCurrencyCode('EUR');
$quote->setQuoteCurrencyCode("EUR");
$quote->collectTotals();

Comment: @BharathN, got solution for this?

Comment: @mohith, I've used sales_order_save_commit_after, so order will be placed with custom currency code, but once invoice created, it is changing to base currency, how can we avoid that?